# SSH agent forwarding is not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, forwarding, ssh-agent

My SSH agent forwarding is not working. [The answer](https://superuser.com/a/169022/167207) from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/168933/extra-configuration-required-for-ssh-agent-forwarding) is quite old and the answer is conflicting with the comments. Can we have an updated answer please?

Basically I can SSH from computer A to computer B, or from computer A to computer C, but not from computer A to computer B, then computer B to computer C. When connecting from computer A to either computer B or computer C, I always use `ssh -A` to force SSH agent forwarding. But I’m still not able to connect computer A -> computer B -> computer C without being asked for a passphrase.

`echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"` works both on the server and my local machine, but on SSH from A -> B, `ssh-add -l` yields:

> The agent has no identities.

Whereas it lists two keys on A.

All three machines are configured with the standard Ubuntu SSH configuration without any changes, the content of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` are posted at http://paste.ubuntu.com/11482964/.

**EDIT:** as per request,

Here is the log of `-Avvv` from B to C:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/myid/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to boxc.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/myid/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/myid/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-1024
debug1: identity file /home/myid/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/myid/.ssh/id_dsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/myid/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: identity file /home/myid/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myid/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myid/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6 pat OpenSSH*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: boxc
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "boxc" from file "/home/myid/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/myid/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com zlib@openssh.com
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com zlib@openssh.com
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA ed:26:20:93:4c:88:ef:17:70:e3:d4:7a:42:4c:8e:69
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.2.122]:21
debug3: put_host_port: boxc
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "boxc" from file "/home/myid/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/myid/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries from file "/home/myid/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/myid/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'boxc' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/myid/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/myid/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f7e....e760),
debug2: key: /home/myid/.ssh/id_dsa (0x7f7e....e7a0),
debug2: key: /home/myid/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/myid/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 149
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 22:32:...:1d:e3
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 22:32:...:1d:e3
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/myid/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plausible explanation is as follows: when you `ssh` from A to B, a shell startup script that gets sourced on B starts an agent local to B.

In case of Bash being your shell on B, [check your `.bashrc` on B](https://superuser.com/a/1616143/432690).

Suppose the script [properly starts an agent](https://superuser.com/a/1734787/432690) local to B. This means it overwrites the relevant environment variable(s) (`$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` essentially) in the shell on B. In effect anything that tries to use an agent in this shell session will find the agent running on B that knows nothing about your keys on A. When you `ssh` from B to C, the agent on B has no identities, you are asked for the passprhase for key `/home/myid/.ssh/id_rsa` stored on B.

If you knew the previous value of `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` on B, you could locate the socket on B that is still connected to the agent running on A. If you (manually) changed `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` back to the previous value, things would start working as you expect. My point is the forwarding itself is not broken, the socket provided by the SSH server on B is there and it works. The issue is your processes on B cannot find it because they find and use the wrong socket instead, due to an agent on B having been started and `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` having been changed.

You can fix this by not allowing the startup script on B to run a new agent. Responsible code is there probably for a reason, so deleting it is not necessarily a good idea. Ask yourself what the reason is. If there is a reason to keep the code then a sane solution will be to make the script check if `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` expands to an empty string and only then set a new agent up.

I cannot be sure if this is what happens *in your particular case*; still I think the scenario is plausible.

Comment: Turned out that it is exactly the case. Thanks Kamil!

Comment: @xpt And it took only about 7 years. :D