# How to fix my ssh key not being forwarded to a specific server

Tags: ssh, fedora, ssh-agent

I have a local host `L` and two remote servers `S0` and `S2`. I can get ssh keys to be forwarded to `S0` but not to `S2`. What's going wrong? See below for details:

```
L = dev29
S0 = testserver0
S2 = testserver2
```

on the local computer `dev29`:

```
[user@dev29 ~]$ head ~/.ssh/config
Host testserver0
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_liberty
   ForwardAgent yes

Host testserver2
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_odmi_dev_2019_rsa
   ForwardAgent yes
[user@dev29 ~]$ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:MdVraEQBZBO2iEGVKVWqN4w+h8CP2iPXIlzQhU65RpE user@dev29 (RSA)
[user@dev29 ~]$ ls -l ~/.ssh/id_rsa_liberty ~/.ssh/id_odmi_dev_2019_rsa
-rw------- 1 user user 1823 Jul 14 12:11 /home/user/.ssh/id_odmi_dev_2019_rsa
-rw------- 1 user user 1675 Apr 22  2013 /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_liberty
```

Forwarding to S0 works:

```
[user@dev29 ~]$ ssh backoffice@testserver0
Last login: Sun Jul 14 20:39:50 2019 from <X.Y.Z>
[backoffice@vs3234 ~]$ ssh-add -l
2048 f1:e9:e7:d6:b3:21:de:94:54:af:c6:42:48:2f:01:e3 user@dev29 (RSA)
[backoffice@vs3234 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
[backoffice@vs3234 ~]$ exit
logout
Connection to testserver0 closed.
```

Forwarding to S2 doesn't:

```
[user@dev29 ~]$ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:MdVraEQBZBO2iEGVKVWqN4w+h8CP2iPXIlzQhU65RpE user@dev29 (RSA)
[user@dev29 ~]$ ssh testserver2
Last login: Sun Jul 14 21:04:09 2019 from 10.137.0.48
[user@testserver2 ~]$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

It would seem that none of the local configuration files are blocking agent forwarding:

```
[user@dev29 ~]$ ssh -vvv testserver2 2>&1 | grep 'Reading config'
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
[user@dev29 ~]$ cat /home/user/.ssh/config /etc/ssh/ssh_config /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config | grep -i forwardagent
   ForwardAgent yes
   ForwardAgent yes
   ForwardAgent yes
#   ForwardAgent no
[user@dev29 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Fedora release 29 (Twenty Nine
```

On the `testserver2`-side, `sshd_config` seems to be OK, and restarting `sshd` doesn't seem to help:

```
[user@testserver2 ~]$ sudo grep -i agentforw /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowAgentForwarding yes
[user@testserver2 ~]$ sudo service sshd restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart sshd.service
[user@testserver2 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Fedora release 29 (Twenty Nine)
[user@testserver2 ~]$ exit
logout
Connection to testserver2 closed.
[user@dev29 ~]$ ssh testserver2
Last login: Sun Jul 14 21:04:22 2019 from 10.137.0.48
[user@testserver2 ~]$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

Possible multiple instances of ssh-agent running as described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528360/ssh-agent-forwarding-troubleshooting , don't seem to be the issue:

```
[user@testserver2 ~]$ ps xaf | grep ssh-agent | grep -v grep
  770 ?        Ss     0:00              \_ /usr/bin/ssh-agent /etc/X11/xinit/Xclients
[user@testserver2 ~]$ exit
logout
Connection to testserver2 closed.
[user@dev29 ~]$ ps xaf | grep ssh-agent | grep -v grep
  714 ?        Ss     0:00              \_ /usr/bin/ssh-agent /etc/X11/xinit/Xclients
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH agent forwarding is not working](https://superuser.com/questions/922003/ssh-agent-forwarding-is-not-working)